# Recursive function to test all the possible combinations and find the smaller one

Tags: arrays, recursion, combinations, allocation, segments

I'm dealing with a problem, trying to make a recursive method that will test all possible combinations and show me the "cheapest" one.

The task is that:

- I have an Array[n] numbers, which was dynamically allocated and filled. {1, 3, 4, 2} for example. The array is defined as
  `int *array;`
- I fond out the size of the array and putted in the variable Size.
- Each 2 numbers in the array indicate the top and bottom of a segment, so in this case the array has 3 segments. The segments are: A = 1 3 ,B =  3 4 ,C = 4 2 .
- I have to join them in the order they are. I can start joining from the last two to the first one or I can start from the center to the sides but I have to choose the "cheapest" way.
- Every time i join two segments: A = 1 3 and B = 3 4 . I calculate the cost of it this way: (1 * 4) + 3. I multiply the numbers at the ends of the segments and Sum to the the number between the segments.
- The input will always be 2 or more segments meaning 3 or more numbers in the Array.

Practically what I need it to do is:

`For two segments: array= "1 2 3"
 A={1,2},B={2,3} ---- (1*3)+2 -> Cost = 5`

`For three segments: array= "30 20 25 10"
 A={30,20},B={20,25},C={25,10} ---- 
case1 - [(30*25)+20] + [(30*10)+25] -> Cost = 1095

case2 - [(20*10)+25] + [(30*10)+20] /> Cost = 545`

So we can clearly see that the second cost is better so we return that value.
For more segments the number of calculations will drastically increase but that's ok for what I need.

I've been trying many times in different ways but I'm getting confused with all the pointers and also that I'm not good with recursion functions.
I don't know if I was specific enough, if something isn't clear I'll be happy to explain.

I sure dont need the whole code, maybe some explanaition or an idea about how to do it would be appresiated :)

Comment: Do you want to know which is the cheapest cost only or also the associated "order"? Does it have to be efficient?

Comment: No i only need to know the lower Cost. I dont need to know anything else, that makes it easier.
About efficiency, Not exactly, i would be happy if it just worked even being it the hard way.

Answer (score 0):

Let `A` be our array of `n` numbers, `A[j]` the jth element and  `A[i,k]` a subarray of A with the ith up to the kth element, including. Index start counting at 0, so that `A = A[0, n-1]`. What is the result of the join operation? For example `A = { 1, 2, 3 }` has two segments `1,2` and `2,3` I assume correctly that joined together that will be `1,3`?

Since each join biparts A in two parts you can recurse by testing all possible joins of `A`, namely `n-2` possibilities, choosing the one with minimal cost. Maybe this equations gives you an idea.

```
/* cost of join two segments of A ending respective starting at j */
cost(A,j) = ( A[j-1]*A[j+1] ) + A[j]

 /* minmal cost of joining(A) when joining at j */
mincost(A,j) = mincost( A[0,j-1] ) + cost(A,j) + mincost( A[j+1,n-1] )

/* test all possible join, use minimal one */
mincost(A) = min[j]: mincost(A,j)
```

End recursion when `n=3`, use `cost(A,1)`.

For a useable algorithm you will probably have to cache `mincost(A[x,y])` this is called dynamic programming.

In C  `A[j]` can be translated to `*(A+j)` where as `A[i,k]` does not directly correspond to a C construct, but it could be roughly translated to the following

```
 struct Array { 
          int * A; 
          int index_first;
          int index_last;
 };
```

Comment: Im not sure what do you mean by A. But what i understand is  that A is the first number of the Array and i test it with the rest of them?
I do not see how would this try to join segment 1 with 2 , segment 3 with 4 and finally join segment 12 with 34..
Im probably missunderstanding the meaning of the A.

Comment: My bet, by accident I changed your `Array` into `A`.

Comment: Oh i get it better now. The way before confused me. Well im gonna try and let you know.